# I got a json.decoder.JSONDecodeError while requesting my IP

Tags: python, json, python-requests, ip

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Host" : "iplocation.com" 
}

res= requests.get("https://iplocation.com/", headers=headers).json()

print(res)
```

Error

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from https://iplocation.com/ is an HTML response, not JSON. This line will return the HTML text response:

```py
res = requests.get("https://iplocation.com/", headers=headers).text
```

You're probably looking for a JSON endpoint to get your public IP address. Something like the following should work:

```py
import requests

res = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json").json()

print(res['ip'])
```

Comment: Please use "if res.status_code == codes["ok"]:" check as well to make sure that the status code is 200